# Bootstrap+Angular6: Toast does not show up until second time i call .toast('show')

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a problem using bootstrap toasts from an Angular 6 application.
It seems like the toast does not appear until second time I call the jquery function to show the toast e.g.:

```
$('#toastScore').toast('show');
```

The (scraped) toast is rendered like this in my template:

```
 <div id="toastScore" *ngIf="scoreMessage" role="alert" class="toast" data-autohide="false" data-animation="true">
  <div class="toast-body">
    {{scoreMessage}}
  </div>
</div>
```

In my component code I'm doing this to enable the toast:

```
setScoreMessage(message: string): void {
  this.scoreMessage = message;
  $('#toastScore').toast('show');
}
```

The first time I call setScoreMessage() the toast does not appear, but the second time it does.
I suspect the issue is that Angular has not rendered the toast into the DOM yet when calling jquery the first time, but I have no idea how to fix it in a good way.

Any input is appreciated.

I'm using bootstrap 4.4.1 and jquery 3.4.1

EDIT: I found a (nasty) workaround by setting a flag when I want to display the toast and checking that flag in the ngAfterViewChecked() event which is later in the lifecycle where the DOM seem to be updated by Angular. If the flag is set in ngAfterViewChecked() I then call jquery to show the toast.
I'm sure there is a cleaner way of doing this so still very interested in getting some advice here.

Comment: Why to use jquery on angular project?

Comment: I'm using jquery only to enable the toasts as this is the only way I've seen so far. If you know of a pure angular way then I'm all ears.

Comment: You can use NG-BOOTSTRAP for angular https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Comment: Yes, thanks - I have seen this, but I have a lot of existing templates that I don't want to convert just for this simple feature(well, what I thought was simple)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `$('#toastScore').toast('show');` in a `setTimeout(...)`? The problem most likely is that your Angular template hasn't rendered yet and your toast library is using the DOM node before it actually exists.